# How to write a function in R to save each dataset to the global environment

Tags: r, function

I am attempting to webscrape each NBA team's results from the previous seasons as follows

```r
schedule <- function(team){
  

team <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",team,"/2023_games.html")
team_log <- team %>% read_html %>%  html_node('#div_games') %>% html_table()

colnames(team_log) <- c("Game", "Date", "Start", "Blank1", "BoxScore", "Blank2", "Opponent", "Result", "OT", "For", "Against", "W", "L", "Streak", "Notes")
team_log <- subset(team_log, !Game == "G")

**.GlobalEnv$team <- team_log**

}

schedule("BOS")

schedule("ATL")
```

My issue is when I run the function for the second time for the Atlanta Hawks, it overwrites the Boston Celtics table. How do I set up my code so that I can have both tables saved in the global environment?

Comment: (1) The canonical way would be something like `assign(team, team_log, envir = globalenv())`. (2) Writing functions that work in side-effect can be much harder to test and troubleshoot, and frankly if I am given a function that attempts to do that, I gut the function and rip the intentional side-effect out. It is contrary to "functional programming", which tends to play a lot nicer (perhaps a subjective assessment). (3) The `$` operator will never work using `$team`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/3358272 (and https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)

Comment: @r2evans, what do you mean by "functions that work in side-effect"

Comment: Functions that work in side-effect are functions that you run and do something that is not returned directly by the function, i.e, you don't assign the result of the function to a new object using `<-`, like your function that tries to write to the global environment instead of just returning the data at the end using `return()`. That can be useful sometimes, but in general it's recommended and expected that functions dealing with data should return/output their result into a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign()` to 'save' objects into your global environment, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

schedule <- function(team){
  team_site <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",team,"/2023_games.html")
  team_log <- team_site %>% read_html %>%  html_node('#div_games') %>% html_table()
  
  colnames(team_log) <- c("Game", "Date", "Start", "Blank1", "BoxScore", "Blank2", "Opponent", "Result", "OT", "For", "Against", "W", "L", "Streak", "Notes")
  team_log <- subset(team_log, !Game == "G")
  assign(team, team_log, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

schedule("BOS")
schedule("ATL")

str(BOS)
#> tibble [82 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ Game    : chr [1:82] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>  $ Date    : chr [1:82] "Tue, Oct 18, 2022" "Fri, Oct 21, 2022" "Sat, Oct 22, 2022" "Mon, Oct 24, 2022" ...
#>  $ Start   : chr [1:82] "7:30p" "7:30p" "7:00p" "8:00p" ...
#>  $ Blank1  : logi [1:82] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ BoxScore: chr [1:82] "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" ...
#>  $ Blank2  : chr [1:82] "" "@" "@" "@" ...
#>  $ Opponent: chr [1:82] "Philadelphia 76ers" "Miami Heat" "Orlando Magic" "Chicago Bulls" ...
#>  $ Result  : chr [1:82] "W" "W" "W" "L" ...
#>  $ OT      : chr [1:82] "" "" "" "" ...
#>  $ For     : chr [1:82] "126" "111" "126" "102" ...
#>  $ Against : chr [1:82] "117" "104" "120" "120" ...
#>  $ W       : chr [1:82] "1" "2" "3" "3" ...
#>  $ L       : chr [1:82] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
#>  $ Streak  : chr [1:82] "W 1" "W 2" "W 3" "L 1" ...
#>  $ Notes   : chr [1:82] "" "" "" "" ...
str(ATL)
#> tibble [83 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ Game    : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>  $ Date    : chr [1:83] "Wed, Oct 19, 2022" "Fri, Oct 21, 2022" "Sun, Oct 23, 2022" "Wed, Oct 26, 2022" ...
#>  $ Start   : chr [1:83] "7:30p" "7:30p" "5:00p" "7:00p" ...
#>  $ Blank1  : logi [1:83] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ BoxScore: chr [1:83] "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" ...
#>  $ Blank2  : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "@" ...
#>  $ Opponent: chr [1:83] "Houston Rockets" "Orlando Magic" "Charlotte Hornets" "Detroit Pistons" ...
#>  $ Result  : chr [1:83] "W" "W" "L" "W" ...
#>  $ OT      : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "" ...
#>  $ For     : chr [1:83] "117" "108" "109" "118" ...
#>  $ Against : chr [1:83] "107" "98" "126" "113" ...
#>  $ W       : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "2" "3" ...
#>  $ L       : chr [1:83] "0" "0" "1" "1" ...
#>  $ Streak  : chr [1:83] "W 1" "W 2" "L 1" "W 1" ...
#>  $ Notes   : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, this can lead to problems and isn't best practice. The comments by @R2Evans / @Bastián Olea Herrera suggest using this type of approach instead:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

schedule <- function(team){
  team_site <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",team,"/2023_games.html")
  team_log <- team_site %>% read_html %>%  html_node('#div_games') %>% html_table()
  
  colnames(team_log) <- c("Game", "Date", "Start", "Blank1", "BoxScore", "Blank2", "Opponent", "Result", "OT", "For", "Against", "W", "L", "Streak", "Notes")
  team_log <- subset(team_log, !Game == "G")
  return(team_log)
}

BOS <- schedule("BOS")
ATL <- schedule("ATL")

str(BOS)
#> tibble [82 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ Game    : chr [1:82] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>  $ Date    : chr [1:82] "Tue, Oct 18, 2022" "Fri, Oct 21, 2022" "Sat, Oct 22, 2022" "Mon, Oct 24, 2022" ...
#>  $ Start   : chr [1:82] "7:30p" "7:30p" "7:00p" "8:00p" ...
#>  $ Blank1  : logi [1:82] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ BoxScore: chr [1:82] "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" ...
#>  $ Blank2  : chr [1:82] "" "@" "@" "@" ...
#>  $ Opponent: chr [1:82] "Philadelphia 76ers" "Miami Heat" "Orlando Magic" "Chicago Bulls" ...
#>  $ Result  : chr [1:82] "W" "W" "W" "L" ...
#>  $ OT      : chr [1:82] "" "" "" "" ...
#>  $ For     : chr [1:82] "126" "111" "126" "102" ...
#>  $ Against : chr [1:82] "117" "104" "120" "120" ...
#>  $ W       : chr [1:82] "1" "2" "3" "3" ...
#>  $ L       : chr [1:82] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
#>  $ Streak  : chr [1:82] "W 1" "W 2" "W 3" "L 1" ...
#>  $ Notes   : chr [1:82] "" "" "" "" ...
str(ATL)
#> tibble [83 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ Game    : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>  $ Date    : chr [1:83] "Wed, Oct 19, 2022" "Fri, Oct 21, 2022" "Sun, Oct 23, 2022" "Wed, Oct 26, 2022" ...
#>  $ Start   : chr [1:83] "7:30p" "7:30p" "5:00p" "7:00p" ...
#>  $ Blank1  : logi [1:83] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ BoxScore: chr [1:83] "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" ...
#>  $ Blank2  : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "@" ...
#>  $ Opponent: chr [1:83] "Houston Rockets" "Orlando Magic" "Charlotte Hornets" "Detroit Pistons" ...
#>  $ Result  : chr [1:83] "W" "W" "L" "W" ...
#>  $ OT      : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "" ...
#>  $ For     : chr [1:83] "117" "108" "109" "118" ...
#>  $ Against : chr [1:83] "107" "98" "126" "113" ...
#>  $ W       : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "2" "3" ...
#>  $ L       : chr [1:83] "0" "0" "1" "1" ...
#>  $ Streak  : chr [1:83] "W 1" "W 2" "L 1" "W 1" ...
#>  $ Notes   : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

One potential issue with this approach is if you want to run `schedule()` in a loop (i.e. apply `schedule()` to a bunch of teams). If that's your goal, one option is to use a for-loop and save the results for each team in a list, then use `list2env()` to 'extract' the dataframes into your global environment (or, better yet, work with the list instead of a bunch of separate dataframes - see e.g. the [purrr package](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/)):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

teams <- c("BOS", "ATL")

output <- list()

for (i in seq_along(teams)) {
  team_site <- paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/",teams[i],"/2023_games.html")
  team_log <- team_site %>% read_html %>%  html_node('#div_games') %>% html_table()
  
  colnames(team_log) <- c("Game", "Date", "Start", "Blank1", "BoxScore", "Blank2", "Opponent", "Result", "OT", "For", "Against", "W", "L", "Streak", "Notes")
  output[[i]] <- subset(team_log, !Game == "G")
}

str(output)
#> List of 2
#>  $ : tibble [82 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ Game    : chr [1:82] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>   ..$ Date    : chr [1:82] "Tue, Oct 18, 2022" "Fri, Oct 21, 2022" "Sat, Oct 22, 2022" "Mon, Oct 24, 2022" ...
#>   ..$ Start   : chr [1:82] "7:30p" "7:30p" "7:00p" "8:00p" ...
#>   ..$ Blank1  : logi [1:82] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>   ..$ BoxScore: chr [1:82] "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" ...
#>   ..$ Blank2  : chr [1:82] "" "@" "@" "@" ...
#>   ..$ Opponent: chr [1:82] "Philadelphia 76ers" "Miami Heat" "Orlando Magic" "Chicago Bulls" ...
#>   ..$ Result  : chr [1:82] "W" "W" "W" "L" ...
#>   ..$ OT      : chr [1:82] "" "" "" "" ...
#>   ..$ For     : chr [1:82] "126" "111" "126" "102" ...
#>   ..$ Against : chr [1:82] "117" "104" "120" "120" ...
#>   ..$ W       : chr [1:82] "1" "2" "3" "3" ...
#>   ..$ L       : chr [1:82] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
#>   ..$ Streak  : chr [1:82] "W 1" "W 2" "W 3" "L 1" ...
#>   ..$ Notes   : chr [1:82] "" "" "" "" ...
#>  $ : tibble [83 × 15] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ Game    : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>   ..$ Date    : chr [1:83] "Wed, Oct 19, 2022" "Fri, Oct 21, 2022" "Sun, Oct 23, 2022" "Wed, Oct 26, 2022" ...
#>   ..$ Start   : chr [1:83] "7:30p" "7:30p" "5:00p" "7:00p" ...
#>   ..$ Blank1  : logi [1:83] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>   ..$ BoxScore: chr [1:83] "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" "Box Score" ...
#>   ..$ Blank2  : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "@" ...
#>   ..$ Opponent: chr [1:83] "Houston Rockets" "Orlando Magic" "Charlotte Hornets" "Detroit Pistons" ...
#>   ..$ Result  : chr [1:83] "W" "W" "L" "W" ...
#>   ..$ OT      : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "" ...
#>   ..$ For     : chr [1:83] "117" "108" "109" "118" ...
#>   ..$ Against : chr [1:83] "107" "98" "126" "113" ...
#>   ..$ W       : chr [1:83] "1" "2" "2" "3" ...
#>   ..$ L       : chr [1:83] "0" "0" "1" "1" ...
#>   ..$ Streak  : chr [1:83] "W 1" "W 2" "L 1" "W 1" ...
#>   ..$ Notes   : chr [1:83] "" "" "" "" ...

names(output) <- teams
list2env(output)
#> <environment: 0x7fa607e6a120>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There are many different approaches that you can use to solve this type of problem in R; the 'best' approach will depend on your use-case, but hopefully one of these will suit. Good luck!